# performSegueWithIdentifier weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I've setup a walkthrough view at the beginning of my app using [BWWalkthrough](https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough) and it works fine. Now I'm just trying to skip that view if the user has already seen it. Pretty simple right? But somehow it is not working. This is what I have:

On my storyboard I setup a segue between the BWWalkthroughViewController and the main view of my app and called it "RootView"
[image]

And this is my code:

```
class TutorialViewController: BWWalkthroughViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var endTutorialButton: UIButton!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Check if should skip this viewcontroller
        let shouldSkipTutorial = NSUserDefaults().boolForKey(Constants.UserPreferences.TUTORIAL_SEEN_KEY)
        if shouldSkipTutorial {
            // In debugger this part is reached but the segue is not executed
            finishTutorial()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Here I setup everything walkthrough related

    }

    // This is called when the user reaches the end of the walkthrough and press the finish button. The weird part is, this works fine! walkthrough is dismissed and next ViewController is pushed.
    @IBAction func endTutorial(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: Constants.UserPreferences.TUTORIAL_SEEN_KEY)
        finishTutorial()
    }

    func finishTutorial() {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowRoot", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Where can the problem be?

Comment: Did you try that code in viewDidAppear?

Comment: No way. It worked! I had tried on viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but none worked. Thanks a lot man!